# Qt QSound Looping

Tags: c++, qt, audio

```
QSound nS("wav.wav");
nS.setLoops(5); //Here i want to loop the sound 5 times.But does not work for me
nS.play();
```

I found this snippet in the help file but it plays but does not loop 5 times.
I do not know what is the problem but my wav file is 50 milliseconds so maybe Qt can not handle this sound file.

Comment: Does your code work with longer sound files?

Comment: What does your code do instead? Is the sound played once?

Comment: @Roku, wait i will try

Comment: @leemes, Yes,played once.

Comment: What is around that code that you show? Is the `nS` instance deleted (getting out of scope) immediately after `nS.play()`?

Comment: Strange,if i use QApplication::processevents, the sound plays once ; if i remove, the setLoops works.

Comment: shouldn't it be void nS::setLoops (5) ?

Comment: @RachelGallen i think no because nS is neither  a namespace nor pointer so it should be used with dot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [sound effect](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtmultimedia/qsoundeffect.html) class

```
QSoundEffect effect;
effect.setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile("wav.wav"));
effect.setLoopCount(5);
effect.setVolume(0.25f);
effect.play();
```

Comment: I am using Qt 4.7.4 Whereas this class comes with 5.0 (I can not use this class)